# Advantage of Mongodb Aribter in mongo replication

Tags: mongodb, nodes, database-replication

I have the following set up in my production environement,

3 nodes, with 1 primary and 2 secondary...

I came to know about the arbiter, Since mongo db itself does the work of election within the replicaset. What is the need of arbiter in the mongo replication?

In which scenario, arbiter will be useful?

Regards,
Harry

Answer (score 1):

The point of an [Arbiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-members/#arbiter) is to break the deadlock when an election needs to be held for a Primary. In such that there are a **majority** of nodes that can make the decision as to which node to elect.

In your current configuration you have an **odd** number of nodes, so the election process is simple when all nodes are up, and in a failover one of the other nodes will simply be elected.

If you have an **even** number of nodes in a replica set to begin with and Arbiter may be required in the case where you do not want to commit the same level of hardware to have say a *five node** replica set. Here you could use an arbiter on a lower spec machine in order to avoid a deadlock in elections.

An arbiter is also useful if you want to give preference to certain nodes to be elected as the Primary.

Plenty of information in the documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-members/

Comment: Neil, Its a good point... But What I don't understand is, Lets consider that I have a 4 node set up, As In articles, blogs have mentioned, Y do I compulsorily need a arbiter... Is that mongo instance cannot manage that

Comment: @Harry not compulsory, as you **could** have another full node in the replica set making five. But if you do not want a full node (this includes non-voting and priority 0 nodes) then you need an **odd number**. That is the case where you set a node as an arbiter. As said, typically a lower spec instance where that matters to you, as otherwise you may as well just add another node to keep the numbers odd. It's a **mini-node** to help make decisions.

Comment: It sohuld be noted that an even number of nodes on a single partition can actually elect without a tie and the decision is not linked to a majoirty of nodees since 90% of the set could have a vote and it would still find a primary

Answer (score 0):

An arbiter enables MongoDB to garnish majority holdings across partitions without the need for a data holding node.

This all stems from the CAP theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem and essentially it enables for one side to have a majority voting as such stops stale mate elections across paritions within your clusters.

Of course Arbiters can be used only on side too if you want say 4 data holding nodes and 1 that is not.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to breaking ties during election, arbiters do not hold data. An arbiter is lightweight and can run alongside other processes. Since it does not participate in a replication/serving queries, it does not use much CPU/memory. Arbiters have minimal resource requirements and do not require dedicated hardware.